# How do I statically link to a lib when creating a command line program in xcode?

Tags: c, xcode, static-linking

I'm new to OSX and XCode and I'm trying to statically link to a C app. I downloaded and installed libconfig and I link to the installed libconfig.a. It works great on my machine but when I run my binary on another machine I get an error that says libconfig.dylib can't be found. Naturally, I don't want to have to install libconfig everywhere I use my app.

I've scoured through the xcode build settings and the only reference I see is the one for libconfig.a. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got this to work. This seems to be a libconfig build issue, maybe expected behavior but it surprised me. I was linking to libconfig.a, but it appears that libconfig.a was linking to libconfig.dylib. I reconfigure libconfig and reinstalled it.

```
./configure --disable-shared
make clean
make
make install
```